# SQL: group and count but only if ALL records are greater than a threshold

Tags: sql

I have a `mytable` in AWS Redshift with `user_id` and `records`. I need to count number of records for each user but only if ALL records for this user are greater than a threshold.

mytable:

```
user_id | records
------------------
0       | 678
0       | 567
1       | 845
1       | 123
1       | 420
2       | 789
```

Threshold = 400 so the result should be:

```
user_id | count
------------------
0       | 2
2       | 1
```

I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` with `having`:

```
select user_id, sum(case when records > 400 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from t
group by user_id
having min(records) > 400;
```

Or using `::`:

```
select user_id, sum( (records > 400)::int ) as cnt
from t
group by user_id
having min(records) > 400;
```

Comment: Thank you again!:)